# Regex PRCE exclude string(s)/ignore string(s)

Tags: regex, delphi

Considering the following code:

```
TFrmLeistung = class(TFrmStandard)
PanelBottom: TsuiImagePanel;
lbDatum: TLabel;
lbLeistungTyp: TLabel;
**TVirtualKosten = record
KostenLeistung,BetragEH,Pauschal: Currency;
ProzentES: Integer;
end;**
FMengeAutoSet:     Boolean;
FMengeAutoSetVal:  Integer;
FLstTxtPopupFunctions: TJX2LstTxtPopupFunctions;
FAfterShowCalled: Boolean;
FBAKuerzel      : TJX2BAKuerzel;
FPseudoLst      : TJX2Leistung
end;
```

is it possible to select the entire code without the code block between double asterisks with regex?
Basically I am trying to extract the class declration without including the record type.
Also it is possible the multi aquirence of such code and I want to escape all of them in the final results.

Comment: In case you want to solve this programmatically: your first regex should match the entire class, and upon inspecting that match have a new regex of whatever region(s) should be deleted - those matches have starting positions and lengths, so you can erase if it from the prime match text.

Comment: the problem is to capturing the class programmatically first i need to get the begining(<classname>=class) till the very last "end;" but middle records (which consist of their own blocks ending with "end;") making it impossible to capture the whole class. I am thinking maybe i do it without regext. but for now goal is to do it only with regex.

Comment: Judging from your (non existing) coding indention style just look for `/^end;\n\n/m`, because it's surely the only `end;` having an empty line afterwards, in contrast to your record ends, which always have a non-empty line afterwards. Also note it's called [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to extract the record type from the class than vice versa!?

Comment: Also I'd like to mention the very powerful refactoring plugin [MMX Code Explorer](https://www.mmx-delphi.de/), maybe you can achieve your goals with it a lot faster!

Comment: This is a question about using a regex, where the input happens to be Delphi code.  As phrased it's not a question about Delphi.  No information is given about the use case so we don't know what's available to the user other than they are trying to use a RegEx.  It's possible the user is trying to convert existing Delphi code to something else, or build an interface to the code in another language, and has no access to the Delphi tool chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'lookahead' and 'look behind'.

This RegEx should work: `/(?<=^end; \xa)(.*)|(^.*)(?=^.* record)/gsm`

However - look-behinds have to be a fixed width, so identifying the end of the record definition is tricky.

This is how it works:

The first alternative captures all text that follows a line starting with `end;`  and having a 'standard' `\n` line ending.  (Note this may not be standard on your platform!)

The second alternative captures all text that is followed by a line that ends with  `record`.

As the look-behind has to be a fixed width the result will be sensitive to how the code is formatted.

You can test this out with your code at regex101
https://regex101.com/